# Appending cells in R based on lookahead regex matching an entire string

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I’m still new to R and regexes, but I’m trying to achieve the following; suppose I have a data table of the following sort:

```
Title               | URL
stackoverflow.com   | https://stackoverflow.com
google.com          | http://
youtube.com         | https://youtube.com
overclock.net       | https://
```

I want to append the cells in column `URL` with their corresponding value in column `Title`, in case `URL` consists only of either `http://` or `https://`, so the desired output would look as follows:

```
Title               | URL
stackoverflow.com   | https://stackoverflow.com
google.com          | http://google.com
youtube.com         | https://youtube.com
overclock.net       | https://overclock.net
```

To do so, I tried using the `sub` function in conjunction with a lookahead regex as follows:

`dt$URL <- sub("(?:^|\\W)https?://(?:$|\\W)", "\\1", dt$Title, perl = TRUE)`

or

`dt$URL <- sub("\\s(https?://)", "\\1", dt$Title, perl = TRUE)`

or

`dt$URL <- sub("\\b(https?://\\b)", "\\1", dt$Title, perl = TRUE)`

But none of the above produces the desired output. The issue is that it doesn’t append/replace anything at all, possibly because the regex doesn’t match anything, or it also matches if there is more data than just http:// or https:// present, i.e. it will also match on a full domain name (which I do not want). How should I adjust my code so that it produces the desired output, given the example input above?

Thank you!

Comment: Why a lookahead? Should be `^https?://$` good enough?

Comment: It's not necessary to use regexes here, `ifelse(dt$URL %in% c("http://", "https://"), paste0(dt$URL, dt$Title), dt$URL)` would do

Comment: I agree with @Aurèle's answer. No regex necessary here. And concerning regex matches, the best is to take an editor capable of regex search (e.g. in ubuntu gedit - activate there regex by Ctrl-H and checking 'Regular expression ... ' and then you can try out all your regex patterns - since the editor will show you interatively which expressions are matching or not.

Comment: If you want to experiment with regexes and work with the RStudio IDE, there's the regexplain addin https://github.com/gadenbuie/regexplain/blob/master/Readme.md . I haven't tried it but it looks promising

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! @Aurèle , thanks for the regexplain addin; I was looking for something similar because I was shooting in the dark with my regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url.col <- c("https://stackoverflow.com", 
             "http://", 
             "https://youtube.com", 
             "https://")

title.col <- c("stackoverflow.com", 
               "google.com", 
               "youtube.com", 
               "overclock.net")

ifelse(grepl("^(\\w*http(s)?://)$", url.col),  # if pattern matches url.col elem:
       paste0(url.col, title.col),    # join content of cols together and return!
       url.col)                       # but if not return url.col element 'as is'

[1] "https://stackoverflow.com" 
[2] "http://google.com"        
[3] "https://youtube.com"       
[4] "https://overclock.net"
```